# Duplicate pointer resource handling in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is my code for some collision detection. I am using pointer to make my code smaller and more readable (The pointer in question being `myBall`). I was wondering if, when creating additional pointers to aim at existing data, one is supposed to `NULL` that additional pointer out or call `.free()` on it, to avoid possible memory losses at runtime.

```
void SceneUpdate(GameScene* myGs){

//Update code for balls
//We get the last existing ball , which is the moving one presumably
Object* myBall = &(myGs->myBalls[myGs->ballCount - 1]);

//If ball is moving
if (!myBall->isStatic){

    //Move according to velocity
    myBall->position.x += myBall->velocity.x;
    myBall->position.y += myBall->velocity.y;

    //Bounce
    if (myBall->position.x < X_MIN || myBall->position.x > X_MAX) myBall->velocity.x *= -1;

    //Collide with ceiling
    if (myBall->position.y < Y_MIN) {
        myBall->velocity.y = 0;
        myBall->velocity.x = 0;
        myBall->position.y = Y_MIN;
        myBall->isStatic = true;
    }

    //After update calc , update collision data
    myBall->maxExtent.x = myBall->position.x + 7;
    myBall->maxExtent.y = myBall->position.y + 7;

    //Values
                            //y                       //RotOn      //ODisable //Shape
    myBall->myAddress[0] = ( ((int)myBall->position.y << 0) | (0 << 8) | (0 << 9) | (0 << 14) );
                            //x                        //HFlip     //VFlip     //Size        
    myBall->myAddress[1] = ( ((int)myBall->position.x << 0) | (0 << 12) | (0 << 13) | (0 << 14) );
                            //ID               //Priority  //Palette
    myBall->myAddress[2] = ( (myBall->colour << 0) | (0 << 10) | (0 << 12) );   

    //Collision check: After Update, for every not static ball, check collision with statics
    //Edit: Only one ball is non Static at max
    Collision(myGs , myBall->ID);   
}
//Else if static , update does nothing. 
}
```

I am under the impression that they don't need the free() method, since I don't want to delete the data they point to. Will they already be handled once they go out of scope?

I use this approach often in my Gba project in order to make code more intuitive so I am worried about possible memory leaks.

Comment: There's no making sense of your question since there's no `malloc` anywhere in sight. Memory leaks and `free` are only relevant when there is a `malloc`. As a rule of thumb, whoever does the allocation should also clean it up. How that translates to your program is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Object* thisBall = myGs->myBalls[index];

    float thisLeft = thisBall.position.x;
//                           ^
```

This can't compile. `thisBall` is a pointer, not a struct (or union). You need `thisBall->position`.

That said, every `malloc` should be paired with a `free`. Your code doesn't `malloc` anything, so there's no need to call `free` either.

> I am under the impression that they dont need the free() method, since I don't want to delete the data they point to.

This is correct.

---

Setting pointers to `NULL` (or any other value) has no direct effect on memory management. In particular, it will not release any memory.

It is also pointless to set variables just before they go out of scope. For example:

```
{
    Object *thisBall = myGs->myBalls[index];
    doStuffWith(thisBall);
    // ...

    thisBall = NULL;
}
```

The compiler will likely just optimize out `thisBall = NULL` because it is a "dead write": `thisBall` isn't used after this line (and it cannot be used because its lifetime ends at the `}`), so there's no need to set it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the dynamic memory allocation (no mallocs, nor reallocs, just local variables in the stack, so they will be managed according to their scope), given that, you don't have to free a non-allocated dynamic memory (your heap is empty).

A hint, why are you using a lot of local float variables? The values are already in the structs `thisBall` and `otherBall`.

Edit: If `myGs` is the variable in the heap, you have to add the code where `myGs` is defined and its allocation is managed.

Answer (score 0):

considering that you didnt use any `malloc`, I will just answer your questions:

every modern operating system will recover all the allocated memory space after a program exits, So yes , they  will already be handled once they go out of scope and you dont have to worry about the memory leaks.

And if you dont use `free()` it would be no harm to it ;except the runtime cost of having more storage than you need which is not your case since you said you  don't want to delete the data they point to. 
But for good style coding, it is better to free the  memory s soon as you don't need it any more.